# How to use google-api-client-ruby calendar stop_channel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api-client, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to use the google-api-client-ruby gem to interface with Google calendar.

I have succesfully setup a channel to watch for events, but I'm struggling to use the stop_channel method to stop watching for events.

The source code looks like it takes a channel object, but if I create a channel object and pass it to the stop_channel method, I get:

> Error - Google::Apis::ClientError: required: Required

My code..

```
channel = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Channel.new(address: "https://www.google.com/", id: 1, type: "web_hook")
begin
  calendar_service.stop_channel(channel)
rescue => error
  puts error
end
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the gem not working?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error `Google::Apis::ClientError: required: Required` means that the request is invalid and should not be retried without modification.

Also, I have seen this [sample code](https://github.com/mmyoji/gcal_booking/blob/4781a3b0e065439acec032c88bcc0829b2000a46/app/models/google_calendar.rb) that uses `stop_channel` method.

```
def stop_channel(channel_id, resource_id)
    channel = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Channel.new(
      id: channel_id,
      resource_id: resource_id
    )
    service.stop_channel(channel)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old at this point but I faced the exact same issue with the newer `google-apis-calendar_v3` gem so I thought I'd post my answer.

In order to get my code working I had to create the channel object with the id and resource_id first.  You might assume just the id would be sufficient but apparently it is not.

Here's the snippet of code that worked for me.

```rb
# Handle Google OAuth
# I'm not sure you need both of these scopes to stop watching a channel but
# my application needed both for other things it had to handle.
client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file("#{ROOT_DIR}/client_secret.json")
scopes = [Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR_EVENTS,
          Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR_READONLY]
token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::RedisTokenStore.new(redis: Redis.new)
authorizer = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.new(client_id,
                                                 scopes,
                                                 token_store,
                                                 '/oauth2callback')

# Create the CalendarService object
service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
service.client_options.application_name = "Quickstart"

if service.authorization.nil?
  service.authorization = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id, request)
end

# Instantiate the channel we want to stop watching using the channel id and
# resource id passed in as request parameters.
channel = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Channel.new(id: params['cid'],
                                                type: 'web_hook',
                                                resource_id: params['resource_id'])

# Stop watching the channel.
service.stop_channel(channel)
```

Hopefully this will be useful to others trying to integrate Google Calendar with a Ruby application.